# Pull / Push to Gitlab Error Deploy in Progress

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

**I'm trying to do Pull / Push to GitLab and get this error in my local git at push / pull:**

```
10:08:14.426: [themes] git -c core.quotepath=false pull --progress --no-stat -v --progress origin master
remote: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: connection refused
fatal: unable to access 'https://user@gitlab.com/AAA/BBBB.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502
10:08:53.791: [themes] git -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin --progress --prune
remote: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: unable to access 'https://user@gitlab.com/AAA/BBBB.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502
```

**On gitlab I get this screen on my browser:**

[image]

This work for me always and today I get the last error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitLab is currently down for maintenance.
See: https://twitter.com/gitlabstatus/status/800714390441967616

Comment: The screen capture says it all, doesn't it?

Comment: I was also confused because I also have deploy webhook and I thought it was a timely problem of my project when doing the deploy.